# Var getter and setter confusion

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am working on a project in swift. I know how getter/setter/didSet works for variables, and that's not what I'm looking for. My project is a SpriteKit game, and I am a bit confused on what should be done. In objective-c, I have always just created a property of my SKSpriteNode, and then used the getter method implementation to access it. However, in swift, this can't be done. That's where I'm confused. The following is how I have it set up already.

My main question is: Should I just do this "workaround" when working in swift

```
func planeNode() -> SKSpriteNode { // use instance var here }
```

or should I do it in the variable's getter method:

```
var plane: SKSpriteNode { get { // use separate SKSpriteNode here and just return }}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you saying that you prefer using `myObj.planeNode()` instead of `myObj.plane` ?  Because if you declare `var plane : SKSSpriteNode` then you get the `getter` for free as `myObj.plane`.  In Swift all properties (stored or computed) are accessed with simple dot syntax.  If you want a function, you must define it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a computed property, backed by a stored property - I used this pattern in C# a lot:

```
private var _plane: SKSpriteNode
public var plane: SKSpriteNode { get { return _plane } set { _plane = newValue } }
```

note however that you achieve the same by just using one stored property:

```
public var plane: SKSpriteNode
```

It's the same happening in obj-c with the `@synthesize` statement (now obsolete because automatically applied). The difference is that the backing data member is available to the class (usually with property name prefixed by the underscore), whereas in swift that data member is not visible at all.

**Addendum** Wondering if I have misunderstood your question. Are you maybe be looking for a way to create a property whose value is calculated? If yes, then use a computer property:

```
public var plane: SKSpriteNode { get { return ... } }
```

Comment: alright, so should I do something like public var plane: { get { var _plane: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(); return _plane; }} ? or how should i go about that?

Comment: hmm no, that would create a new instance every time you use the getter. I think `public var plane = SKSpriteNode()` is all you need - and if you don't reassign plane, then you can make it immutable by using `let` in place of `var`: `public let plane = SKSpriteNode()`

Comment: ahh, i gotcha now. I was used to using the getter way of working around my issue from objc, but I understand how it works now